# how do i create a flutter pub quiz app with a start button for the timer to be started from the mc's back-end

Tags: flutter

I have been requested to do an app for a company looking to have it at live events. The clients will use the app to answer the questions but they want the mc to have a timer start when the mc wants to start the question for a duration and end all sessions once the main timer completes. I know how to do this for an offline timer per each device but have no idea how to start a timer for all devices at the same time to make sure people are not cheating. If anyone can point me in a direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You could look at firebase as a central point from which you emit messages to the other devices. (And vice versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a database that the mc app can set a value to, and the patron app can read from. Any database will do; Firebase is pretty simple and easy to set up and can do a lot for free. One app needs to set a time value to the database when the start button is pushed. Other apps need to be listening to / streaming that value.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen
https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore